# Unbiased estimator for variance when each $x_i$ has probability $p_i$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

Suppose we have a sample of 3 "observations" $x_0, x_1, x_2$ from a PMF of *unknown mean*, where we know that each observation $x_i$ has probability $p_i$.

Then a biased estimator of the mean is $\bar\mu := \sum_{i=0}^2 p_i * x_i$.

Also:

0. An estimator of the variance is $\sum_{i=0}^2 p_i * (x_i - \bar{\mu})^2$, where $\bar{\mu}$ is as above.
1. Another estimator of the variance is $\sum_{i=0}^2 {1 \over N} * (x_i - \bar{\mu})^2$, where $\bar{\mu}$ is as above.
2. Another estimator of the variance is $\sum_{i=0}^2 {1 \over N -1} * (x_i - \bar{\mu})^2$, where $\bar{\mu}$ is as above.

Estimator 2) is what's usually used as an unbiased estimator (ie. Bessel's correction), but I think that should only make sense when the probability of each $x_i$ is the same (ie. each observation is equally likely, ie. $p_i$ equals $p_j$ for all $i$ and all $j$), which is not true in general, so I don't think Estimators 1) and 2) are correct for this situation.

- What's an unbiased estimator for the variance in this case?
- What are some (other) nice estimators for the variance in this case?
- How can one add a Bessel-type correction to Estimator 0)?
- Does any of this changes if, instead of *knowing* the probability $p_i$ of each $x_i$, we rather *estimate* the probability $p_i$ from the observations themselves?

Comment: What does "where we know that each observation $x_i$ has probability $p_i$" mean?  Probability of having been observed?  You observed all three of $x_0,x_1,x_2$

Comment: Yes, we observed all 3 $x_0, x_1, x_2$, and we know they were generated by a PMF where the probability of $x_0$ is $p_0$, the probability of $x_1$ is $p_1$, and the probability of $x_2$ is $p_2$.

Comment: Then $\sum\limits_{i=0}^2 p_i \, x_i$ is not an unbiased estimator of the mean unless $\sum\limits_{i=0}^2 p_i  =1$

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know